# Using variables in smarty template system?

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

Here is the current code I'm using in my .tpl file:

```
{php}
$userid = $this->_tpl_vars['clientsdetails']['userid'];
extract($this->_tpl_vars);
$query = "SELECT id FROM tblaffiliates WHERE clientid=".$clientsdetails['userid'];
$result = mysql_query ($query);
$data = @mysql_fetch_array ($result);
if ($data['id'] > 0)
{
        $this->assign('affiliateid', $data['id']);
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(tblaffiliatespending.amount) FROM tblaffiliatespending JOIN tblaffiliatesaccounts ON tblaffiliatesaccounts.id=tblaffiliatespending.affaccid INNER JOIN tblhosting ON tblhosting.id=tblaffiliatesaccounts.relid INNER JOIN tblproducts ON tblproducts.id=tblhosting.packageid INNER JOIN tblclients ON tblclients.id=tblhosting.userid WHERE affiliateid=$affiliateid ORDER BY clearingdate DESC");
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$pendingcommissions = $data['pendingcommissions'];
$this->assign("pendingamount", $pendingcommissions);
{/php}
```

However, it's returning a blank field wherever I mention `{$pendingamount}` on my page.

I think the problem may be with where I have `WHERE affiliateid=$affiliateid` because when I change `$affiliateid` to an actual number, the code will work.   However, it does appear that `$affiliateid` should work because when I add `{$affiliateid}` anywhere on the page, it does show the affiliate's ID number.

Can anyone figure out why `{$pendingamount}` would be showing blank whenever I add it on the page?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your script is [prone to SQL injections](http://bobby-tables.com) and also [the mysql extension is deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). You should switch to [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) and use prepared statements.

Comment: huh, smarty is still alive... :(

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, can either of your see what would be causing the variable to show blank when I add it on the page?